# An unusual limit

Tags: calculus, analysis, computational-mathematics

I a reading an article in neural coding.
It cintains a limit which I cannot understand.
(It remindes the benomial sum but it didn't work for me)
I am talking about $(22) \Rightarrow (23)$ in the picture below.

Any help?
Thanks!

**EDIT**

The problem here is to show that, as $N \log{f} \to 0$,

$$\left (1-f^{-N} \right )^{p-1} \sum_{S=0}^{p-2} \binom{p-1}{S} \left (f^{N}-1 \right ) \log_2{\left (\frac{p}{S+1} \right )} \sim (p-1)\log_2{\left (\frac{p}{p-1} \right )}  N \log{f}$$

[image]

Comment: "Easily" seems to be a very subjective word :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, this is a fairly straightforward procedure.  Recognize that $f^N = e^{N \log{f}}$.  Then as $N \log{f} \to 0$,

$$\left ( 1-f^{-N} \right)^{p-1} \sim (N \log{f})^{p-1} $$
$$\left ( 1-f^{-N} \right)^{-S} \sim (N \log{f})^{-S} $$

Also note that, in the sum, the quantity $(N \log{f})^{-S}$ increases greatly for increasing $S$.  Thus, you need only consider the $S=p-2$ term in the sum.  Plug the numbers in and you get your Eq. (23).

Comment: got it.. $lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}=1$. Thanks!!